# True purpose of celebrating Eid-Al-Adha

Tags: sacrifice, eid-ul-adha

For the past couple of days, I have been trying to understand Eid-Ul-Adha and its history in deep detail; this question is part of that understanding I am trying to have.

I am trying to understand the true purpose of Eid-Ul-Adha celebrations. Below are three of the purposes that I have come across:-

1. It is done to commemorate the happenings of Prophet Ibrahim. But nowhere in Quran it is specifically mentioned that do sacrifice animals to commemorate the happenings of Prophet Ibrahim. Also nowhere it is mentioned how this Sunnah of Ibraheem started. Also I can not find a satisfactory answer as to why Allah asked Prophet Ibraheem in the first place to sacrifice his son.

> https://quran.com/2/196?translations=20
> https://quran.com/5/2?translations=20
> https://quran.com/22/28?translations=20
> https://quran.com/22/34?translations=20
> https://quran.com/22/36?translations=20
> https://quran.com/6/162?translations=20
> https://quran.com/108/2?translations=20
> https://quran.com/37/107?translations=20
> https://quran.com/37/107?translations=20
> https://quran.com/16/123?translations=20

Above are some of the references in the Quran where it has been talked about the sacrificing of animals but nowhere it has been explicitly mentioned to do this to commemorate the happenings of Prophet Ibrahim.

2. Another purpose that I have been told is that by sacrificing an animal, Allah wants to check one's willingness and piety to sacrifice a loved one in the name of Allah but this is not applicable as nowhere a sacrifice of an animal can be compared with the sacrifice of a human being. It does not even come close to that as many people nowadays do not have even keep sacrificial animals as pets for a long time. They just buy it a week ago and sacrifice the animal. Also, there are permissions that you can have another person sacrifice the animal for you which again kills the purpose. You can still choose not to look at the sacrifice of animals again killing the purpose.
3. Somewhere I read that animals are sacrificed on this day to mark the end of the Hajj but again this applies to the people who have gone for the Hajj and not to those who are sitting afar. The below surah mentions the same if I am not wrong.

> https://quran.com/2/196?translations=20

Please clarify!

Comment: This question is unfocused and argumentative. The purpose of sacrifice is the same as the purpose of performing wudu, prayers, fasting, itikaf, tawaf or any other ritual worship: It is to gain closeness to Allah through the means that He has prescribed. It is also the spending of property in a way that He has ordained.

Comment: @UmH: I am sorry if you found my question unfocused or argumentative but I am not sure how much clear I can be with my question. Based on my understanding of Eid-Ul-Adha from the questions I have asked on this forum and what I could find on the web, I have framed this question with all the relevant links as well.

Answer (score 1):

Muslims celebrate Eid-ul-Adha by first offering Eid prayer and then sacrificing an Udhiyah (animal of the an’aam class) because

1. To glorify Allah and show piety.
2. It is Sunnah mu’akkadah (a confirmed Sunnah) or fard (obligatory).
3. To commemorate Prophet Ibrahim's devotion to Allah and his readiness to sacrifice his son.

> **Allah's Glory in Sacrifice:**
>
> Their meat will not reach Allāh, nor will their blood, but what reaches Him is piety from you. Thus have We subjected them to you that you may glorify Allāh for that [to] which He has guided you; and give good tidings to the doers of good. — Saheeh International
>
> [22:37](https://quran.com/22?startingVerse=34)

> **Sunnah of Prophet Muhammad:**
>
> The Prophet said:
>
> **“Whoever offers a sacrifice after the prayer has completed his rituals (of Eid) and has followed the way of the Muslims.”**
>
> [(Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 5545)](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5545)

> **Ibrahim's Sacrifice:**
>
> 99. He said: "I will go to my Lord! He will surely guide me
> 100. "O my Lord! Grant me a righteous (son)!"
> 101. So We gave him the good news of a forbearing son.
> 102. Then, when (the son) reached (the age of) (serious) work with him, he said: "O my son! I have seen in a vision that I offer thee in sacrifice: now see what is thy view!" (The son) said: "O my father! Do as thou art commanded: thou will find me, if Allah so wills, one of the steadfast!"
> 103. So when they had both submitted (to Allah), and he had laid him prostrate on his forehead (for sacrifice),
> 104. We called out to him "O Abraham! ...
> 105. "Thou hast already fulfilled the vision!" - thus indeed do We reward those who do right.
>
> [37:99 to 37:109](https://quran.com/en/as-saffat/99-109)

Comment: About your 1st point that you mentioned i.e. Allah's Glory in Sacrifice , if you read the Surah carefully, the sacrifice is being mentioned for only those people who are coming to Hajj (22:28) and nowhere in this Surah it has been mentioned something like "O people of the whole world, on this particular day you are mandated to sacrifice the animal no matter you are coming for Hajj or not", then how can we assume that Quran has revealed Eid-Ul-Adha for all the Muslims all across the world whether they are doing Hajj or not. Please clarify on this.

Comment: About your 2nd point you mentioned i.e. Sunnah of Prophet Muhammad , this means this is not mandatory and must as per Quran and might be a recommendation for the Muslims and the same has been talked about in this question as well : https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43210/is-offering-a-sacrifice-on-eid-ul-adha-required .  And the Hadith you mentioned is referring to the day of Eid, which is referring to 10th of Dhu’l-Hijjah which is again associated with Hajj and the people who are doing it. Then it again comes back to the same thing that this has been mentioned only for Hajj people.

Comment: About your 3rd point you mentioned i.e. To commemorate Prophet Ibrahim, can you please give me a verse from the Quran which explicitly & specifically mentions and apply to all the eligible Muslims (who can afford an animal for sacrifice) around the world (doing Hajj or not) that you have to sacrifice an animal to commemorate the happenings of Prophet Ibrahim?

Comment: @Ganit 
> Quran which explicitly & specifically mentions and apply to all the eligible Muslims (who can afford an animal for sacrifice) around the world (doing Hajj or not) that you have to sacrifice an animal to commemorate the happenings of Prophet Ibrahim?

The Qur'an almost never goes in such details, that is what sunnah is for. The Qur'an only provides signs and very minimized commandments that are explained by the hadith and comprehended by scholars. What specifically are you looking for?

Comment: Salaam @SyedM.Sannan : Then can you please share the hadith that "explicitly & specifically mentions and apply to all the eligible Muslims (who can afford an animal for sacrifice) around the world (doing Hajj or not) that you have to sacrifice an animal to commemorate the happenings of Prophet Ibrahim?"

You have written "The Qur'an only provides signs....", can you please share those signs in the Quran which mandate Eid-Ul-Adha for all Muslims around the world and again I am not asking for signs related to sacrifice being done during Hajj. I hope you get my point.

Thanks !

Comment: All I am trying to understand and validate in respect to Quran is that being a vegan Muslim and an animal lover, am I mandated to offer sacrifice on Eid-Ul-Adha or not and till now I have not got any satisfactory answer that mandates this act.

Comment: @Ganit Allah created the animals for our service, he even created the entire universe for the service of humans that he created for worshipping him. I'll send in the ahadith shortly but as I said, since Qur'an provides signs, it usually doesn't give explicit directions, so the verses in regards to the sacrifice in hajj are the signs towards it. Now the details for the sacrifices and on whom it is obligatory on are provided into ahadith. The people who comprehend the Quran and Hadith are scholars and laymen take from scholars. However, since you have asked, I'll attach the hadith here.

Comment: @Ganit and btw, you can be a vegan Muslim if you want, but the reason should not be in opposition of eid ul adha or considering it animal cruelty, as that would be sinful. The reason can be that you don't like to eat meat, or have allergies, etc.

Comment: @Ganit Also, one thing I wanted to point out is that sacrificing on eid ul adha IS NOT an obligation, the majority of scholars hold is that, is that it is sunnah muakkadah.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan : So Eid-Ul-Adha is not mandatory but recommended then, right?

Comment: @Ganit 

"So perform the Salah [ritual Prayer] for your Lord and slaughter [an animal] (Surat Al-Kawthar, 108:2)."

This is a command to the Prophet PBUH in the Qur'an, although, again, not a direct commandment to the believers, but the general ruling is that when the Prophet PBUH is commanded of something, it is also appointed for the believers unless specified otherwise.

Ibn Majah 3123: "“Whoever can afford it, but does not offer a sacrifice, let him not come near our prayer place.”"

Comment: @Ganit Ibn Majah 3125: "“We were standing with the Prophet (ﷺ) at ‘Arafat and he said: ‘O people, each family, each year, must offer Udhiyah and ‘Atirah.’

Comment: @Ganit as for your question, that depends on the school of jurisprudence you follow, if you are a Hanafi, then their opinion is that it is wajib (mandatory). If you follow other schools, then all of them hold that it is sunnah muakkadah (a recommended and verified sunnah) as far as I know.

Comment: See again there's contradiction, https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3125 tells that Prophet Muhamamd PBUH is making it "must " for all people to offer sacrifice then again you are saying that there are different schools of thought in which one says it is mandatory while others say it as a recommended and verified sunnah.
The same is being argued here as well : https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43210/is-offering-a-sacrifice-on-eid-ul-adha-required.
So one can assume that the hadith you mentioned viz. https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3125 might be wrong or not verified.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan : I am not doubting Eid-ul-adha as animal cruelty or anything like that, but I am just trying to get the answer about that is sacrificing applicable to all the Muslims around the world who are not part of Hajj or is it just a practice we have picked up over the time on the sayings of various Muslim clergymen without any valid justifications for this?

Comment: @Ganit No, no Hadith can ever be wrong or not verified all sahih hadith are equally valid and it is necessary upon all Muslims to accept them. The work of verifying what hadith is right or not is ONLY and solely a work for scholars, that they have done for us. It is mandatory upon laymen to follow one madhab specifically, so if you want to, you can follow the Shafi'i madhab where you don't have to do the eid sacrifice. Also, there are multiple ahadith that look contradictory word-by-word but both are equally sahih and reconciled by scholars.

Comment: @Ganit "over the time on the sayings of various Muslim clergymen without any valid justifications for this?" There is no such thing, in Islam, scholars are authority and laymen aren't even allowed to review the Qur'an and Hadith in a researchful manner. Not a single practice is in existence that is "made up" by clergymen. But there is no point in continuing this discussion since this is going off-topic from the question itself.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan: Thanks for all the comments/answers!
So the gist is that in the Quran, the sacrificing ritual has been mentioned only for the people who go for Hajj (following the Sunnah of Ibraheem) and not for the worldwide but as per hadith it is asked of every capable Muslim around the world to sacrifice an animal on Eid-Ul-Adha to follow the sunnah of Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) but on this, there are two schools of thoughts; one in which is it is mandatory and one i.e. Shafi'i Madhab where it is not obligatory and hence one can choose any one of the schools and do accordingly.

Comment: @Ganit No problem. Most of that is right, except the Qur'an's mentioning part that it specifcally talked about the people doing hajj. Did you see the verse I quoted here of surah al kawthar?

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan : Yes, I read that surah. It translates to "So be grateful to Allah for this blessing, by performing prayer for Him alone and offering sacrifice for Him, as opposed to the offerings of sacrifice the idolaters do for their idols." But here as per my understanding this part is only talking about sacrificing in general sense and not particularly about the sacrificing ritual of Eid-ul-adha. This surah also tells a similar thing https://quran.com/22/36?translations=20 but again nothing specific to Eid-Ul-Adha.

Comment: @Ganit The reason for that is that there is no mention whatsoever of *any* eid in the Qur'an. As I said, the Qur'an only gives signs to what is important, and the details are mentioned in the Hadith along with things that aren't explicitly mentioned in the Qur'an and the scholars of the 4 schools of jurisprudence reconcile them, following all 4 of which is following the sunnah. I think your doubts are cleared by now though, and I am glad if they are.

Comment: If however, you have anything more to discuss, it would be better that we move this conversation to chat because comments are not for extended discussions.

Comment: No I am done! Thanks !